# Why C is not install with vim

Tags: vim, terminal

Vim is written in C but when I install it on my terminal only Vim install, Why not C ? How terminal understands c source code of vim?

Answer (score 2):

When you install vim (or any other program), you don't install the source code of the vim (or any other program), but the binary executable with some supporting libraries already compiled.

So the C-compiler or any other language compiler is not required, as you don't compile, you already execute the built program.

Comment: But how I can create executable of my programs.

Comment: Use g++ or gcc compiler, but this is another question already.